# pass multiple parameters dynamically to ashx file

Tags: c#

is this sysntax is correct `<%"ImageHandler.ashx?iid="+ Eval("ImageId") +"&pid="+ Request.QueryString["plant"].ToString() +"&uid="+ Session["AccountId"] %>`

Comment: can you explain more are you using, jscript,Jquery? AJAX?

Comment: correct maybe, but a good idea, no. It's completely illegible for humans, and prone to break at the slightest unexpected condition. What happens when the QueryString does not contain a key "plant", the ToString() will fail horribly. And is Eval("ImageId") always there? Some points to consider...

Answer (score 0):

Make it a post request and put things in the form variables.